# Date related columns missing from find_or_initialize response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app and want to assign some Date (not Datetime) columns of an Advert model.

The model schema is as follows, including 2 Date columns - 'start' and 'end'.

```
create_table "adverts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "product_id"
  t.date "start"
  t.date "end"
  t.boolean "expired", default: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

The Advert controller also permits update of these columns,

```
def advert_params
      params.require(:advert).permit(:user_id, :product_id, :start, :end, :expired)
end
```

I then have a method in the controller that is intended to update an advert.

The route is

```
post 'update_advert', :on => :collection
```

The advert record is pulled / created using find_or_initialize.

```
def update_advert
    @advert = Advert.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: advert_params[:user_id], product_id: advert_params[:product_id])

    logger.info "checkpoint1"
    logger.info advert_params.inspect
    logger.info "checkpoint2"
    ...
end
```

This gives the following log output,

```
I, [2020-05-19T12:32:46.947732 #13110]  INFO -- : [e741ba19] checkpoint1
I, [2020-05-19T12:32:46.948986 #13110]  INFO -- : [e741ba19] <ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>1, "product_id"=>1000, "expired"=>false} permitted: true>
I, [2020-05-19T12:32:46.949151 #13110]  INFO -- : [e741ba19] checkpoint2
```

Note the start and end columns are missing, which therefore prevents me from going on to update them.

If I 'show' the record via the standard Rails web interface, I see the fields as expected.

If I pull the record via the JSON api, I see the expected fields.

```
{"id":4,"user_id":1,"product_id":1000,"start":"2020-05-18","end":"2020-06-18","expired":false}
```

My question is - why are the start and end columns not returned as part of the find_or_initialize response?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You have not posted how you are calling `update_advert` it appears that you are not passing this information in to the method

Comment: @engineersmnky The method is invoked via a POST that includes advert_params, and may or may not refer to an existing record.  I've updated the question to include that.  Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you mixing up the `advert_params` with the `@advert`? One are the request parameters, the other is the object that is return from the database (or initialized if not found). Have you looked at the output of `logger.info @advert.inspect`?

Comment: @pedrosfdcarneiro Thank you! I was adding in the fields to advert_params later in that method, but you put me on the right track. I had to copy the new start & end values to @ advert and then the update saved the changed fields as any changes in supplied advert_params.  Please post your suggestion (add start & end to @ advert) as the answer and I will accept. Thanks again!